# NGINX location block with limited number of path segments

Tags: nginx

I have a path which starts with `~* /api/v1/(?<endpoint>.*)`. But I realize this can be misused. Is there a way to limit the number of path segments *after* the `/api/v1` to only 3 while still being able to retain any GET variables if any?

So these will pass:

- `/api/v1/foo`
- `/api/v1/foo/bar`
- `/api/v1/foo/bar/baz`
- `/api/v1/foo/bar/baz?x=hello&y=world`

these won't:

- `/api/v1/foo/bar/baz/aaa`
- `/api/v1/foo/bar/baz/aaa/n`

I'm only looking at a total of 3 path segments max *after* `/api/v1`. Anything more than that shouldn't match. Is this possible in a location block? I'm open to suggestions.

After this I use `proxy_pass` on the capture group to pass it on to my FastAPI backend along with any GET variables which might exist so `/api/v1/foo/bar` gets received as `/foo/bar`.

**Update:**
Added GET variables I forgot earlier.

Comment: Try: `location ~* "^/api/v1/(?<endpoint>[^/]+(/[^/]+){0,2})$"`

Comment: @RichardSmith Pls post this as the answer so I can mark it as such.

Comment: @RichardSmith can this be modified so if there are too many path segments it returns a 444 instead? I tried modifying your code but regex was never one of my strongest suits.

Comment: You can add another location, for example: `location /api/v1/ { return 444; }` which will match if the regular expression does not.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the regular expression in your question, you will need to change the `.*` sequence (which matches anything), into a sequence that only matches one, two, or three path elements.

For example:

```
[^/]+(/[^/]+){0,2}
```

For completeness, you should use the `^` and `$` anchors as you are matching to an entire string. *Note that the query string is not part of the normalised URI tested by a location statement.*

Finally, Nginx requires any expression containing braces to be protected by quotes.

---

So, you could use a [regular expression location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) as follows to match only the permitted URLs:

```
location ~* "^/api/v1/(?<endpoint>[^/]+(/[^/]+){0,2})$" {
    ...
}
```

A URL with too many path elements will be processed by some other location block. Generally, if no regular expression location matches a URL, the prefix location with the longest matching prefix will be used.

So, the following prefix location will match any URL that begins with `/api/v1/` but **does not match** the regular expression location above, including those URLs with too many path elements:

```
location /api/v1/ { 
    return 444; 
}
```